# Find the set of values of $a \in R $ for which $ x^2 + i ( a - 1 )x + 5 = 0 $ will have a pair of conjugate imaginary roots .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

My solving so far :

Roots of the equation are :

$$ { (1 - a )i \pm \sqrt { -a^2 + 2a -21 } } \over 2 $$

Now there will be conjugate roots if -a^2 + 2a -21 > 0 , but its not . 
Now I have two things going in my mind :

1 ) $  \sqrt { -a^2 + 2a -21 } $ can give complex result so that

$ { ( 1 - a )i \pm \sqrt { -a^2 + 2a -21 } } $ gives conjugates .

2)  $ {-a^2 + 2a -21 } $ is not a perfect square even in complex plane and thus our expression $ { ( 1 - a )i \pm \sqrt { -a^2 + 2a -21 }  } $ would never give us conjugate roots . 
$ \implies $ the only way $ x^2 + i ( a - 1 )x + 5 = 0 $ will give conjugate roots if a = 1 , so that we get $ x^2 = -5 $  . But I concluded this after seeing the book's answer i.e $ a \in \{1\} $.

Tell me a way to systematically solve it than just analysing it .

Comment: Answer was "$x \in \{1\}$" or just "$\{1\}$"? Since the question was about values of $a$, answer stating something about $x$ doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Abstraction opps , thats supposed to be a $\in {1} $ . I have edited it .

Comment: 1) Roots must be imaginary, so $-a^2+2a-21 \le 0$. Done. 2) Roots must be conjugate, so their sum $(1-a)i$ must be real. This implies $a=1$.

Comment: @Abstraction thanks....

Answer (score 5):

The sum of the roots will always be $i(1-a)$ and if the roots are conjugate then this quantity should be real. That leaves $a=1$ as the only possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sqrt { -a^2 + 2a -21 }=i \alpha, \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ then the only roots are $i\frac{1-a\pm\alpha}2$ so  no conjugate  pair unless $1-a=0$.

The case $\sqrt { -a^2 + 2a -21 }=\beta, \beta\in\mathbb{R}$ gives roots 
$i\frac{1-a}2\pm\frac{\alpha}2$ so no conjugate pair at all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this equation yields:
\begin{align}
x=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{2} i \left(a-i \sqrt{-(a-2) a-21}-1\right)\\
+\frac{1}{2} \left(-i a+\sqrt{-(a-2) a-21}+i\right)
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Retriving the imagininary parts of this solutions we have:
\begin{align}
\Im(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\Re\left(\sqrt{21 + (a-2) a}\right) -a \right)\\
\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\Re\left(\sqrt{21 + (a-2) a}\right) -a\right)
\end{cases}
\end{align}

If there are complex congulgated, then $\Im(x_1) + \Im(x_2)=0$, so:
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\Re\left(\sqrt{21 + (a-2) a}\right)-a+1\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\Re\left(\sqrt{21 + (a-2) a}\right)-a+1\right)\\
0&=1-a
\end{align}
Therefore, their root are complex conjugated iff $a=1$.